# On Chrome, Youtube and Google search frequently doesn't load because of "failed to load resource"

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, google-search

Sometimes (randomly) when I search on Google, I get a white page. When I open developer console, I see "failed to load resource"

This only happens on Youtube and Google on Google Chrome.  I've reinstalled Google Chrome, cleared cache, etc. Cleared history, etc.

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=hello&aq=f&oq=hello&aqs=chrome.0.57j61j0j60l3.703j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
```

I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome.

Version 26.0.1410.65

Sometimes, Youtube loads half the page. (always the same half)

When I refresh it, everything is fine.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue after disabling all extensions?

Comment: Yes. Even disabling all extensions it's the same.